# Will a male cockatiel take care of 5 day old babies on its own?

Tags: feeding, cockatiels, parrots

Our female cockatiel died today. They have 2 babies which are around a week old. Will the male feed and take care of the babies by itself? What should we do?

Comment: Be aware that this is a question and answer site, that may not provide an answer in a timely fashion. This sounds like a medical emergency and you should contact your vet for specific instructions. If you don't receive an answer, in a few days, you may be the most knowledgeable person on the subject/  Please return and post an answer to help others in the future.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I encourage my cockatiels to continue feeding their chicks when they stop?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/how-do-i-encourage-my-cockatiels-to-continue-feeding-their-chicks-when-they-stop)